# iOS data stays the same after switching view controllers

Tags: ios

Im making an app that basically just tracks your speed and elevation and plays a song. It uses storyboards. It has multiple view controllers. If I am currently tracking the data on the app and playing a song, and then switch to another view, when I switch back everything is messed up. It is no longer tracking, and the music controls are all messed up. How do I switch view controllers without changing what is taking place on the view that I am switching from?

Comment: When you say changing views, do you mean switching view controllers?

Comment: yes, switching view controllers with a segue

Comment: `everything is messed up. It is no longer tracking, and the music controls are all messed up` Could you please clarify what `messed up` means? Does this only happen when you pop view controllers (i.e. go back to a previous view controller in your navigation controller's stack)?

Comment: yes. And messed up meaning that the app is no longer tracking. Its as if I exited the app and cleared it from multitasking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configure your view contents in

-(void)viewDidLoad

dont use 
viewWillAppear or 
ViewDidAppear

unless its mandatory

Comment: I have not used view will appear or view did appear